# class assignment help- read input into a parser

Tags: c++

Here is a starting point that my instructor has provided us. I am having trouble finding a way to read input from a command in UNIX environment such as "ls" or "hist" using the provided parcer gettoks(). gettoks() is linked from a .l that has the code for the parser. how can toks (which is declared as a pointer to a pointer) be used to pass a line of input into gettoks() that will parse it (i will then return appropriate system call based on the input) ive tried using fget but get a compiler error. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
//*********************************************************

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    // local variables
    int ii;
    char **toks;
    int retval;

    // initialize local variables
    ii = 0;
    toks = NULL;
    retval = 0;

    // main (infinite) loop
    while( true )
    {
        // get arguments
        toks = gettoks();

        if( toks[0] != NULL )
        {
            // simple loop to echo all arguments
            for( ii=0; toks[ii] != NULL; ii++ )
            {
                cout << "Argument " << ii << ": " << toks[ii] << endl;
            }

            if( !strcmp( toks[0], "exit" ))
                break;
        }
    }

    // return to calling environment
    return( retval );
}
```

Comment: Use `ls | yourcommand`. Then your program will read from stdin as per normal.

Answer (score 0):

This the solution which you can use to parse.

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    // local variables
    int ii;

    for(ii=0;ii<argc;ii++)
    {
    cout << "Argument " << ii << ": " << argv[ii] << endl;
    }
    // return to calling environment
    return 1;
}
```